# Maps Api JavaScript - Problema ao salvar local pesquisado no banco de dados MySql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, mysqli, google-maps

Preciso que quando o usuario clique no botão salvar que é exibido quando o marker recebe um click, as informações do local sejam salvas no banco de dados.

Campos ocultos que recebem os valores do local quando pesquisado:

```
            <input type="hidden" name="lat" id="lat">

            <input type="hidden" name="lng" id="lng">

            <input type="hidden" name="rua" id="rua">

            <input type="hidden" name="bairro" id="bairro">

            <input type="hidden" name="cidade" id="cidade">

            <input type="hidden" name="cep" id="cep">
```

Códigos para (teoricamente) passar as informações para o arquivo que faz a conexão:

```
 // Define o que sera extraido da busca 
       var address = ''; //Endereço recebe nulo para posteriormente receber parametros em forma de array
       if (place.address_components) { // se o local tiver informações extras(componentes como cep, rua, bairro etc)
         address = [ // atribuindo os valores desejados a variavel address
           (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''), // Numero do local
           (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''), //Logradrouro, vulgo: nome da rua
           (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || ''), // bairro
           (place.address_components[3] && place.address_components[3].short_name || ''), //cidade
           (place.address_components[6] && place.address_components[6].short_name || '') //cep

         ].join(' ');
       }

      var item_Lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
      var item_Lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
      var item_Numero = place.address_components[0];          
      var item_Rua = place.address_components[1];
      var item_Bairro =place.address_components[2];
      var item_Cidade =place.address_components[3];
      var item_Cep = place.address_components[6];

      $('#name').val(place.name);
      $('#lat').val(item_Lat);
      $('#lng').val(item_Lng);
      $('#rua').val(item_Rua);
      $('#bairro').val(item_Bairro);
      $('#cidade').val(item_Cidade);
      $('#cep').val(item_Cep);

      // Exibe na infoWindow o Endereço e informações do local
      infoWindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + name + '</strong><br>' + address + '<br><form method="POST" action="processa_cad.php"><input type="hidden" name="lat" id="lat"><input type="hidden" name="lng" id="lng"><input type="hidden" name="rua" id="rua"><input type="hidden" name="bairro" id="bairro"><input type="hidden" name="cidade" id="cidade"><input type="hidden" name="cep" id="cep"><input type="hidden" name="name" value=""><input type="hidden" name="type" value=""><input id="btnCadastrar" class="form-control btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Salvar"></form>');

        marker.addListener('click', function(){
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition()); // centraliza o mapa no marcador atual, iniciado anteriormente
      });
```

Arquivo processaCad.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
// ob_start();
require("conexao.php");

//Receber os dados do formulário
$cep = $_POST['cep'];
$rua = $_POST['rua'];
$cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
$bairro = $_POST['bairro'];
$lat = $_POST['lat'];
$lng = $_POST['lng'];
$type = $_POST['lng'];
$name = $_POST['name'];


//Salvar os dados no bd
$result_markers = "INSERT INTO enderecos(id_in_endereco,   cep_in_enderecos, logradouro_in_enderecos, cidade_var_enderecos, bairro_var_enderecos, lat_in_enderecos,  long_in_enderecos, nome_st_local, tipo_st_local ) VALUES 
            (2,  '$cep', '$rua' , '$cidade', '$bairro', '$lat','$name','$type')";

$resultado_markers = mysqli_query($conn, $result_markers);
if(mysqli_insert_id($conn)){
$_SESSION['msg'] = "<script  type='text/javascript'>alert('Local salvo');window.location.href='mapa.php'</script>";
header("Location: mapa.php");
}else{
$_SESSION['msg'] = "<script  type='text/javascript'>alert('Local não salvo');window.location.href='mapa.php'</script>";
header("Location: mapa.php");   
}
```

Quando eu pesquiso um local, ele me retorna ele no centro do mapa com um marcador sob o local com algumas informações como mostrado acima. O problema é quando eu clico no botão salvar, ele apenas recarrega a pagina processando a requisição, mas sempre da erro ao cadastrar.

Os unicos valores que aparecem corretos nos campos do tipo hidden são so de Latitude e Longitude. Os demais retornam `[object Object]`

Meus campos no banco estão da seguinte forma:

[image: Atributos do banco]

Comment: Coloque o erro na pergunta. Apenas uma observação, se você está cadastrando a latitude e longitude, não vejo necessidade de cadastrar os demais dados, você pode buscar esses dados pela api do maps quando necessário

Comment: Então, na verdade ele não me retorna um erro especifico. Apenas não cadastra no banco como deveria. E eu preciso cadastrar os outros dados para controle no cadastro dos usuarios

Comment: As variáveis estão com o valor correto? pode usar `var_dump($POST)` no php (não esquece de tirar o redirecionamento para ver o valor)

Comment: Os unicos valores que aparecem corretos nos campos do tipo hidden são so de Latitude e Longitude. Os demais retornam [object Object]

Comment: Por isso o erro ao inserir no banco, verifique se está pegando os dados corretos da api do google maps

Comment: Eu vou dar uma revisada em como estou recebendo as informações, mas se souber de alguma forma de fazer isso, por favor me diga kk mas muito obrigado mesmo assim

Comment: Se quiser ajuda com isso, coloque na pergunta como você está pegando os dados e um link com exemplo de json retornado

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela atenção Guilherme, consegui resolver o problema. Só esqueci de postar aqui!